# Should a 403/404 supersede a 405 response?

Tags: api, rest, http

On a RESTful API, imagine a certain endpoint doesn't support a particular request method, let's say DELETE requests are not allowed for that object type.

And also suppose an authenticated user that does have some access across the API, but doesn't have delete access on *anything*, makes a DELETE request to this endpoint.

Should the response be a 403 or a 405?

And also the same question with 404s too.  Imagine a request is from an authenticated user, who has been set to disabled (or had ALL permissions removed), and they have a typo in the URL and hit a non-existent endpoint. We know it's a 404, but even if they correct their typo it'll be 403. So should the response to the non-existent endpoint be 404, or just a 403?

In both cases, semantically the 404 or 405 seems more 'correct', but should the security adage of erroring on the side of revealing less, take precedence?

I have a feeling that most would think the 404 should stand, but that the 405 should be a 403.  But if so, why the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The response should give the client the information that's most relevant, which in this case is a 403:

> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

Consider the extreme scenario: the entire API requires an authentication token, and none was provided. Should the server proceed to validate the request, check if the resource exists, and tell the client the result? That implies that all resources are partially public - their existence can be checked with no authentication at all.

The per-resource scenario is just an extension of the same principle: as soon as the server knows the current user is not authorised for that resource, it should stop processing and tell them so. It doesn't need to proceed to validate the request, and see if that particular method is applicable to that particular resource.

A complex application might have auth checks in multiple places:

- *authentication* ("are the credentials provided valid?") can happen as soon as the headers can be read, before even examining the rest of the request
- some *authorisation* ("does this user have access to this") can be built into the routing system, e.g. "for all URLs starting /bookings, require the 'bookings' permission"
- some frameworks support more complex checks as middleware or callbacks attached to specific routes, e.g. "for /bookings/{company}/{id}, check that the user belongs to {company}"
- other checks may happen after the request has been dispatched to a controller/action, e.g. "if the user only has permission to see their own bookings, check the user ID of the booking after you retrieve it"

As soon as any of these checks fails, the application should stop processing: retrieving a booking from the database which you already know you're going to refuse to show it to the user is a waste of resources at best, and a security vulnerability at worst.

Comment: So would you also expect auth to be done before URL routing? In the case of 404, arguably until you can figure out what they're trying to access, you don't know if they have permissions or not - perhaps SOME resources are free to access without any permissions.

Comment: this all makes perfect sense.  Annoyingly it's preventing execution of code that I'm trying to achieve :) I have built a pretty in-depth permissions system allowing fine-grained control over access levels to object instances and children thereof.  The actual issue I have is that this component checks the body of the POST to see if you have perms on the parent to create a child.  But in unit tests, I just want to hit the API with empty body, and get 405 (creation not allowed) and not have the access manager bother to look at the request body to figure if you WOULD have access.

Comment: (Previous comment incorporated into answer.) I don't follow. Your unit tests should be testing the behaviour that you want the system to have, not taking short-cuts that wouldn't apply to real users. If you need to test what happens in service X if service Y returns a 405, the test should be mocking the response from service Y. If you want to test how an empty body would behave if the user had particular access, mock the access manager to report that access. Probably I'm just misunderstanding your description.

Comment: I had to rewrite my comment a few times to fit in the character limit - so it's not described well.  I do have a solution for it now in the unit tests, so it's all fine, and your explanation makes sense.  But in short, in my *particular* case, the access manager is actually doing  extra work to figure out if the user would have access to delete a resource, that isn't necessary since the DELETE method is disallowed anyway for that endpoint.  So I had expected the 405 to come first for the same reason you gave - why bother access checking the action if the API doesn't allow the action anyway?

Comment: @DavidDownes Hm, I think I see where you're coming from now. In that case, maybe a 405 _is_ the right response - it's like if you ask "Do I have access to /download-more-ram on Amazon.com?" The answer isn't "no", it's "there's no such thing".

Comment: Yes, precisely :) Which is also why I also extended the question to include asking about 404, coz it's like "I dunno if you have permission or not ... the thing you're asking for makes no sense!", because that was my own brain's line of reasoning

Answer (score 1):

> Should a 403/404 supersede a 405 response?

HTTP doesn't tell you what the answer should be; it just gives you a common language for describing the answer that you do give.

404 and 405 are cacheable responses by default, 403 is not.  That will sometimes make a difference.

For security reasons, we will sometimes [deliberately offer a misleading response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3), in order to avoid leaking information.

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).

But the choice of precedence can simply be a matter of choosing which status code you prefer to see in your access logs for this case.